# shortcut for hiding parameter info popup intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea, vim, ideavim

`Ctrl+p` seems to be only showing the popup but doesn't toggle it. There is no action to hide it AFAIK.
I have already set delay of 10 secs for showing parameter info popup. But still it seems idea lacks this feature.

I am using ideavim and `Ctrl+[` doesn't hide the popup. I need to press escape twice and again `i`/`a` to actually hide the popup.

Is there any shortcut for hiding documentation popup?

Comment: Hi! Could you please file an issue on IdeaVim YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM and attach logs and `~/.ideavimrc` file? https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files

Actually, it should work fine with a single ESC.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. single escape doesn't work. first it goes to escape mode and then actual escape is functional. Also, is this what you are telling me to issue or the actual feature that is action to hide the popup?

Comment: You could create a macro that does: escape twice then `i`/`a`. I know IntelliJ IDEA has built in macro support which can be accessed via ctrl+shift+a on Win10, then typing macros in the popup menu.

Answer (score 0):

I have filled the issue for IdeaVim plugin: [VIM-2160](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-2160). Please vote/follow.